# haproxy config fails to redirect browser to https on fully qualified drupal8_parallax_theme slideshow images

Tags: drupal-8, haproxy

I have a drupal8 site using the drupal8_parallax_theme as its theme, which relies it seems on a flexslider library for a slideshow displayed at the top of the site.

The images are being rendered in the html source as fully qualified, using the http protocol.  This results in a warning displaying on my ssl certificate in the browser's location bar.  I followed multiple sources of guidance on this, seeking to leverage the settings.php file on the drupal8 site, adding a redirect in .htaccess on the container running the site and now, most recently with a conditional in my haproxy configuration.

I am open to anything which might work, and suspect that the most elegant solution would be a change in the upstream code so that it used a relative link for these locally hosted files.  But hoping to avoid having to manually patch this theme every time this site gets rebuilt, I'm focused for the moment on an haproxy approach.

My question is:  why is this not working, please?

```
  acl is_www_mydomain hdr_dom(host) -i www.mydomain.com
  acl is_www_mydomain hdr_dom(host) -i mydomain.com
  redirect scheme https code 301 if is_www_mydomain !{ ssl_fc }
```

Any guidance offered would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time taking a look at this.

-- Hugh Esco

Answer (score 1):

I advise you not to use hdr_dom(host) but hdr(host) instead.

Read the link below
[HAProxy: hdr_dom(host) with redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757508/haproxy-hdr-domhost-with-redirects)

Please note, the two acls have the same name.

```
acl is_www_mydomain hdr(host) -i www.mydomain.com mydomain.com
redirect scheme https code 301 if is_www_mydomain !{ ssl_fc }
```